# How show that in triangle $ \sqrt {a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 4S\sqrt {3}} \geq \frac {2S\sqrt {2}}{d}$?

Tags: geometry

Denote $ S$ be the area of triangle $ ABC$, $ BC = a,CA = b,AB = c$. Let $ D,E,F$ be on sides $ BC,CA,AB$ such that $ DE = EF = FD = d$. How show that $ \sqrt {a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 4S\sqrt {3}}$$ \geq \frac {2S\sqrt {2}}{d}$?  I have no idea how to do this, can this be proved with simple geometry?

Comment: i think you must have a typo  because the RHS is scale- invariant but the LHS can be arbitrarily small by replacing a,b,c by a/n,b/n,c/n. And is that $S$ in the LHS or $S^2$?

Comment: @user254665: The scales are correct since $S$ is an *area*, so both sides of the equation have the unit of distance.

Comment: sorry. i was thinking of a common notation where s denotes half the perimeter, and i was reading too fast.